# MongoDB lookup to various collections based on a field value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Consider there is documents like this in DB:

```
{
   name: 'my list',
   items: [
      { type: 'book', id: 5364 },
      { type: 'car', id: 354 },
      { type: 'laptop', id: 228 }
   ]
}
```

I need to grab data of each item from its own collection, based on `type` value.

I searched about it but couldn't figure out the correct approach.

Expected output:

```
{
   name: 'my list',
   items: [
      { type: 'book', id: 5364, data: [{...}] },
      { type: 'car', id: 354, data: [{...}] },
      { type: 'laptop', id: 228, data: [{...}] }
   ]
}
```

**Mongoose schema of first collection (above):**

```
{
   name: String,
   items: {
      type: Array,
      default: []
   }
}
```

And other collections that must be looked up has corresponding `_id` field.

Comment: Can you post your schema?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to do this. To be most similar to what you have currently, you just need to make one small change. `type` is a keyword in Mongoose, so if you want to have a field in your schema which is actually called "type", you need to use the word twice. Once for the Mongoose keyword and again to define your schema.

```
{
 name: String,
 items: [{
   type: { type: String},
   id: Number,
   data: []
  }]
}
```

If the `data` field is coming from another collection, you could use a reference and then call `populate()` on your find method.

```
// ItemSchema
{
 name: String,
 items: [{
  type: { type: String },
  id: Number,
  data: [{
   type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   ref: 'OtherSchemaName' 
  }]
 }]
}

// Find Method with populate
const myList = await ItemSchema.find({type: "book"}).populate('data')

// Result
{
 name: 'my list',
 items: [
   { type: 'book', id: 5364, data: [{...}] },
 ]
}
```